# Java Thread and Interrupt, Strong Puzzle

Tags: java

```
public class InterruptTest extends Thread
{
   public void run() 
   {
     try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Finished!");
      } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("I am interrupted!");
        System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());// showing the result after exception throw as well as flag set to false
        System.exit(-1);
      }
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        InterruptTest t1 = new InterruptTest();
        Thread t= new Thread(t1);

        t.start();
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());// ask for the judgment in first time before calling interrupt().

        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());// ask for the judgment in second time after calling interrupt().
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());// ask for the judgment in third time after calling interrupt(). Very Puzzled!!!
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());// ask for the judgment in fourth time after calling interrupt().
   }
}

Console Display:

false// sure 
true// not sure 
true// not sure
true// not sure
I am interrupted!// sure
false// sure

false// sure 
true// not sure
true// not sure
false// not sure
I am interrupted!// sure 
false// sure 

false// sure 
true// not sure
false// not sure
false// not sure
I am interrupted!// sure 
false// sure
```

The code concerns with Java Thread and interrupt() method. Can you tell how it gives me the unexpected results obtained by running the same code several times? Why aren't these results unique?  ....................................................................................Thank you all!

Comment: Feel free if you are not clear about my puzzle! Let me supplement!☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a concurrency behavior, it means that each of the threads are running in a simultaneous way that you will not be able to judge which one starts and which will stop.

Comment: Note that there is a thread wrapping your `main` metho, so you have more than one thread

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your meaning, I just use t.isInterrupted() successive three times after calling interrupt(), it should give me three same results.

Comment: I said that you have to consider the main thread also, you cannot know when your threzd is being interrupted, just put in mind that the instructions inside the thread are not sequential anymore